# Sorting a vector where tie-breaker elements are lazily computed

Tags: c++

I want to sort a vector of structs by a primary field and use a secondary field as a tie-breaker. The normal way would be this:

```
struct element {
  int primary;
  int secondary;
};

bool comparator(const element& e1, const element& e2) {
  if (e1.primary != e2.primary) {
    return e1.primary < e2.primary;
  }
  return e1.secondary < e2.secondary;
}
```

But the secondary data is expensive to compute. As it is only needed when the primary values are equal, I want to compute it lazily.

It seems the only place I can do this lazy evaluation is within the comparator itself. Something like:

```
bool comparator(const element& e1, const element& e2) {
  if (e1.primary != e2.primary) {
    return e1.primary < e2.primary;
  }

  return e1.computeSecondary() < e2.computeSecondary();
}
```

While this will avoid evaluating the secondary for the cases when the primary values are different, it will end up recomputing the secondary values for the same element each time it is compared with another element. The data I want to sort is long tailed with something like 30% of values equal to 1, 20% equal to 2, 5% equal to 3, and lower % for higher values. So, there will be fair number of cases where the secondary element will get computed, and not storing the computed values could result in them being recomputed too many times.

So, I would like the secondary values to be evaluated at most once per element. But the comparator takes const ref arguments, so it can't modify the secondary value of the element. How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Possible options are, in a nutshell.

1. Declare `secondary` mutable.
2. Use `const_cast` in `comparator`.
3. Use `const_cast` in `computeSecondary`.
4. Create a simple `Lazy` template class that either holds a value or a thunk and, when asked for, internally forces a value if it hasn't been evaluated yet and reports the result (or immediately reports a result, if it is already known), does not take long; and declare `secondary` as of type `Lazy<int>`.
5. Or rather do not reinvent the wheel and use `std::future` that is actually that very Lazy template (in one case).
6. Or anything else, one can create more approaches.

Comment: Using const_cast in the comparator seems the most straightforward. Would I just const_cast each of the arguments to the comparator and then call its computeSecondary(), which would also update the secondary value itself?

Comment: Yes, for instance. And you only `const_cast` in case there's a tie on primary keys.

Comment: Cache or memoization member variables are often declared as `mutable` in order to avoid the need for a `const_cast`.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know about mutable. Did some googling. As you said, that is a better choice in this case.